# Work on new joomla template in way that only I can see changes?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Is it possible to install new template and adjust website to it, without anyone else seeing changes until i decide to go public?

Comment: Are you asking how to test in production? If not, the answer is easy: test on a test server, then make the changes to your production server after they definitely worked right.

Comment: It is not necessary to test it in production, but to keep my articles categories,modules etc.. so i can adjust template to my site and then publish changes. Btw, I think that answer below is right thing i need, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are ways you can do this.

**Specify Template in URL Parameter**

You can install the new template and specify the new template via a parameter in the url like this: https://website.com/index.php?template=newtemplatename

**Test Pages**

You can create test menu options and assign these menu options to the new template in the Menu Assignment tab in the template settings.

**Alternatively Set Up a Test Copy**

Unfortunately, the above testing methods may not work very well as a new template will likely have different module positions and names so your modules may not display as you would expect.

For this reason, it is often easiest to make a test copy of your website where you can change the module position names to suit the new template for a complete test.

It can be fairly straightforward making a copy of a Joomla website using the free or paid version of Akeeba Backup and Akeeba Kickstart and placing the new website in a sub directory such as /test or similar without interfering with the live website.

Comment: Hm last solution seems okey, that way i could backup site with database and setup it on my pc keeping all articles, pages, categories etc.. work on it and then with Akeeba Kickstart upload all my changes and exclude database beacuse new articles will be published, am i right ?

Comment: A local test copy is a good way to go. It would probably be best to apply the changes back on the live website manually as some changes (e.g. module settings) are stored in the database.